# Meaning of 'Accuracy' reported during Training in Keras/Tensoflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Training a classifier.   During training, 'Accuracy' is shown and updated with each mini-batch.  The meaning of 'Accuracy' is clear when we run a Test batch, but during training, how is it computing 'Accuracy'?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. How is training different from testing when it comes to calculating accuracy?

Comment: yeah, its kinda a dumb question -- I should have asked more specifically why I see the training accuracy jump up with the first mini-batch of a new epoch.  I think I understand what its doing now -- see my comment to answer below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Training accuracy is the accuracy you get when you apply the model on the training data. Like you would apply it on the test data, instead, training data is passed to the model for generating predictions. And, these predictions are the compared with the original labels for measuring accuracy.

And, the mini-batch accuracy reported during training corresponds to the accuracy of the particular mini-batch at the given iteration with that subset of training data, averaged over the previous mini-batch accuracies.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now.  But I think your answer is not quite right -- I don't think the accuracy reported is just computed for the current mini-batch -- I think the accuracy shown is updated with the completion of each mini-batch, but it is the average accuracy over all the mini-batches seen so far in the current epoch.  This would explain what I often see: the reported training accuracy generally jumps higher as a new epoch is started -- because then it drops the averaging from the prior epoch that was generally at a lower accuracy.

Comment: Exactly, the train acc is estimated and updated with the acc achieved on every minibatch. Otherwise, it would have to process the entire train set making the training a lot slower.

Comment: Yes, you are right there. Thats what I meant to convey. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

The `accuracy` is a metric that indicates the number of correctly predicted examples over the total of examined examples. So, it is a completely general concept, which is not performed just during testing phases.

While the accuracy of the test set let's you understand how the model actually performs in a real context, the accuracy of the training set let's you understand how your model is progressing in terms of its learning.

The comparison between training and test metrics is useful when you want to know for example if the network is overfitting your training data.

Just to make a very **simplified** example, if you notice that your network has 98% of training accuracy but just 60% of testing accuracy, it is a signal that it is not able to generalize when it comes to predict data that it has never seen before. And this can be caused by overfitting.

Obviously, the accuracy is not the only metric to watch in order to find training issues, but it is as relevant as the others.